# Specflow loses log4net appenders in AfterTestRun

Tags: c#, log4net, specflow

I want to log my Specflow output and further logging into a single file with log4net. 
The log appenders get configured via the app.config and get loaded in the BeforeTestRun with Priority 0. Afterwards I am able to log into the files and  *LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders()* contains all 3 appenders.

As soon as it reaches AfterTestRun, the *LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders()* contains 0 appenders.

```
[BeginTestRun(0)]
public void beginTestRun(){
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
   //LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders() contains 3 appenders
}

[AfterTestScenario(MaxPriority)]
public void afterScenario(){
    //LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders() contains 3 appenders
}

[AfterTestRun(0)]
public void afterTestRun(){
    //LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders() contains 0 appenders
    //does reinitiate all loggers, but configuration of object can get lost
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Is there a way to keep the appenders and log configuration also in AfterTestRun? Or why is it lost? Does it affect to other static members too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/):

> As most of the unit test runners do not provide a hook for executing logic once the tests have been executed, the `[AfterTestRun]` event is triggered by the **test assembly unload event**.

When the test assembly unloads, the loaded configuration goes away with it. If you want to log in this method, you will have to load the configuration again.